# Возможно ли запустить python код из строки?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Существует строка:

```
str = 'print("Hello world!")'
```

Представляется ли возможным исполнить этот код из строки? Существует ли библиотека, позволяющая это реализовать?

```
execute_code_from_string(str)
```

Вывод:

```
Hello world!
```

Comment: `exec(str)` . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужна встроенная функция `exec`.

```py
str = 'print("Hello world!")'
exec(str)
```

Из документации Python: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec

Comment: eval выдаст ошибку например на `a = 1`

Comment: @andreymal действительно, перепутал с `exec` по аналогии с JavaScript. Отредактировал ответ.